# Submiting a form after clicking the submit button to perform an AJAX query, unexpected results

Tags: php, ajax, forms, click

I have a form, I have a submit button. On click of the submit button, I suspend the form from submitting and peform an AJAX request. This sometimes works and sometimes doesnt. Can you see any flaws in the code below?

```
$('#ambition_submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var output = getTimelineEntryData(data.toJSON());//console.log(output);
    $.getJSON('http://www.test.com/x/api/add_subgoals.php',{action:'add.subgoals',ambition_id:ambition_id,subgoals:output}, function (response) {
        //var this_url = this.url; console.log(this_url);
        if (response.status == 200) {
            var result = response.message;//alert(response.message);
            $('form[name=testing747]').submit();//console.log('Test ' + $('form[name=testing747]').length);
        }
        else{
            alert(response.message);
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Is `ambition_submit` id only once on the page?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? how is it behaving?

Comment: @Perry yes, declared only once as "<button id="ambition_submit">Submit</button> "

Comment: @MihaiIonescu Sometimes the form submits without running the AJAX, sometimes the form doesnt submit at all and performs the AJAX. Meaning my form doesnt get validated. It might just be down to good old debugging?

Comment: check the code returned by the php with each submit attempt, maybe it's not returning what you expect, all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I previously had some issues with `click` in the past.
I changed it to `live` and fixed those issues. Maybe it won't fix yours, but you could give it a try:

```
$('#ambition_submit').live('click',function(){
});
```

For the most recent jquery version, it has been replaced by `.on` though.

Hope that helps!